# How to pass an element from a title, then passed into a function in R Notebook?

Tags: r, function, parameters, r-markdown, title

I am trying to define an element that appears in the title into a R Notebook that I wish to be automatically embedded, or picked into a function. That is because I have 100 hospitals that I have to produce a report for. Therefore, I want to be effective as possible.

Here it is. I want to pass the hospital name into the title that I wish later one to be picked by the functions made by myself.

Here is an example of the notebook I have in R:

[image]

And here is the function I have in one of the chuncks:

[image]

One of my parameters in the function I have is `hospital_name`. I want the hospital name to be appearing first, in the beginning of the R Notebook section, after title as I will have the title and then the hospital name. But then the same parameter, hospital_name that I am hoping to appear after the title, should be automatically picked by my function so that the analysis are done. Is there a way to do this in R Notebook?

And this is my code:

````
---
title: " Project"
author: " secret :) "
date: "`r format(Sys.Date(), '%b %d, %Y')`"
output:
  pdf_document:
    toc: true
    number_sections: true
  rmarkdown::html_vignette: default
subtitle: Process Measure Report
vignette: |
  %\VignetteIndexEntry{Vignette Title} %\VignetteEngine{knitr::rmarkdown} %\VignetteEncoding{UTF-8}
---

```{r setup, include=FALSE}

knitr::opts_chunk$set(
  collapse = TRUE,
  comment = "#>",
  echo = FALSE,
  warning = FALSE,
  message = FALSE
  
)

library(magrittr)


```


```{r}
# choose dates intervals for the analysis and the hospital name 

start_date <- as.Date('2020-04-01', tz = 'Europe/London')
end_date <- as.Date('2021-03-31', tz = 'Europe/London')
hospital_name <- 'Whiston Hospital'

```


in the function appears the hospital_name:


```{r method_admission_initial_diagnosis, echo=F, results='asis', fig.height=5, fig.width=7, cache=TRUE }

method_admission_initial_diagnosis <- 
  mnp::method_admission_initial_diagnosis(data = mnp_std, hospital = hospital_name, start_datetime = start_date, end_datetime = end_date, plot_function = FALSE)

knitr::kable(method_admission_initial_diagnosis, 
             caption = "Number of patients by method of admission and initial diagnosis")


```
````

Comment: Can you include your markdown code as text (which can be copied) instead of an image (which cannot be copied) ?

Answer (score 0):

If you load the `rmarkdown` library, you can access the metadata of the YAML front data in the object `metadata`. Then if the titles follow the pattern "<Hospital Name> Project", you can extract the hospital name with

```
hospital_name <- sub("(.*) Project", "\\1", metadata$title)
```

Comment: I have done it but got an error: 'Error in is.factor(x) : object 'metadata' not found'

Comment: I have uploaded the rmarkdown library yet it gave me an empty character

Comment: Do you load it in the file with `library(rmarkdown)`?

Comment: Yes, and then got an empty character. It doesn’t give anymore the error but it gives me an empty character. The pattern though isn’t the Hospital Name Project. It is Hospital Name Process Measure Report, in subtitle. So I replaced metadata$subtitle.

Comment: Indeed, but it is the same even for the title

Comment: Try `hospital_name <- sub("(.*) Process Measure Report", "\\1", rmarkdown::metadata$subtitle)`.

Comment: hospital_name <- sub("(.*) Process Measure Report", "\\1", rmarkdown::metadata$subtitle)
> hospital_name
character(0)

Comment: Are you knitting the file or just running the code interactively? If you haven't yet, try knitting the file.

Comment: Got this error. And if you backtrace it - the issue lies in rmarkdown:render . Could it be that when it gets the hospital name, it is not within the qoutes? the output of your code should give me hospital_name <- 'Hospital name' not hospital_name <- Hospital Name.                                                                                                    
Quitting from lines 79-87 (test_rnotebook.Rmd) 
Error: Can't subset columns that don't exist.
x Column `Definite MI` doesn't exist.
Backtrace:
     x
  1. +-rmarkdown::render(...)

Comment: my question though is do you get a character into the hospital_name ? If you do a test on an rmarkdown that I have sent. I just want to know what you get in the hospital_name? Because if you do not get anything and tells you it's contains 0 characters  then I believe knitting the file does not make sense at all.

Comment: and if I pass this alone hospital_name <- 'Whiston Hospital' - I get my output knitted into a PDF. It is worth mentioning this is R Notebook.